# Why mongodb sort by _id is much faster than sort by any other indexed field?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm trying to fully sort a collection with millions of rows by a single field.
As far i know, ObjectId contains 4 bytes of timestamp. And my timestamp  is 4 bytes integer indexed field. So i suppose sort by _id and timestamp should be simular, but here's results

```
db.coll.find().sort("_id", pymongo.ASCENDING)
# takes 25 minutes to run
```

and

```
db.coll.find().sort("timestamp", pymongo.ASCENDING)
# takes 2 hours to run
```

why is this happening, and is here the way to optimize that?
Thanks

UPDATE

The timestamp field i'm trying to sort with is already indexed as i pointed

collection stats

```
"size" : 55881082188,
"count" : 126048972,
"avgObjSize" : 443,
"storageSize" : 16998031360,
"capped" : false,
"nindexes" : 2,
"totalIndexSize" : 2439606272,
```

and I dedicated to mongodb proccess 4gb of ram (tried to increase to 8gb but speed didn't increased)

UPDATE 2

It's turned out how much sorting on field order follows insertion (natural) order, so much the sorting speed is faster

I tried to

```
db.new_coll.create_index([("timestamp", pymongo.ASCENDING)])
for el in db.coll.find().sort("timestamp", pymongo.ASCENDING):
    del el['_id']
    db.new_coll.insert(el)

# and now
db.new_coll.find().sort("timestamp", pymongo.ASCENDING)
# takes 25 minutes vs 2 hours as in previous example
```

Comment: What is the format of timestamp field you are using?

Comment: @PardeepSingh 4 bytes Unix time (like 1523386147)

Comment: Seriously, even your sort on `_id` takes quite some time. I'd assume that either we have a problem with RAM or we are talking of a sharded cluster. Please add information about your RAM utilization and your setup, including the size of your database (size, not only number of entries!) to your question [by editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49760024/edit). Side note: there is no notion of a row in MongoDB. The sooner you stop applying a SQL mindset to MongoDB, the better.

Answer (score 1):

Sorting by _id is faster because of the way _id field value is generated.

Words from [Documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/objectid/)

> One of the main reasons ObjectId’s are generated in the fashion
>   mentioned above by the drivers is that is contains a useful behavior
>   due to the way sorting works. Given that it contains a 4 byte
>   timestamp (resolution of seconds) and an incrementing counter as well
>   as some more unique identifiers such as the machine id once can use
>   the _id field to sort documents in the order of creation just by
>   simply sorting on the _id field. This can be useful to save the space
>   needed by an additional timestamp if you wish to track the time of
>   creation of a document.

I have also tried explaining the query and noticed that nscannedObjects and nscannedObjectsAllPlans is 0 when sorting is done using _id.

```
> db.coll.find({},{_id:1}).sort({_id:1}).explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor _id_",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 353,
        "nscannedObjects" : 0,
        "nscanned" : 353,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 0,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 353,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : true,
        "nYields" : 2,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "_id" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "server",
        "filterSet" : false
}
```

Comment: You aren't seeing any documents scanned in your explain output because you are explaining a [covered query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) where all of the fields in the query projection (in your case, `{_id:1}`) can be answered using entirely using the index. This is unrelated to the format of the `_id` value.

Answer (score 1):

Indexes.

> When you use the MongoDB sort() method, you can specify the sort order—ascending (1) or descending (-1)—for the result set. If you do not index for the sort field, MongoDB will sort the results at query time. Sorting at query time uses CPU resources and delays the response to the application. However, when an index includes all fields used to select and sort the result set in proper order, MongoDB does not need to sort at query time. Instead, results are already sorted in the index, and can be returned immediately.

Please check here for more details.
https://mobile.developer.com/db/indexing-tips-for-improving-your-mongodb-performance.html

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

Answer (score 0):

_id field is auto created which stores a 12 byte ObjectId value upon insertion of a document into collection of MongoDB database representing unique value into a BSON document belonging to collection.

According to documentation of MongoDB

```
The 12-byte ObjectId value consists of:

a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
a 3-byte machine identifier,
a 2-byte process id, and
a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.
```

Indexes defined on fields of collection speed up retrieval process of data stored into database collections as values belonging to indexed field are sorted into specific sort order and scanning of documents stops once matching value is found thereby minimizing number of documents to scan.

An unique index is defined on  _id field  during creation of collection and hence sorting data by _id field facilitates fast retrieval of data from collection.